# SharePoint Foundation 2013 - Advise on using PowerShell to remove old files?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

So, i am stuck in an awkward situation.  My employer is deploying a new service, and decided to use SP Foundation 2013 (for reasons i can't understand, other than cost i assume).

The problem is, they tacked on the requirement that old files be automatically removed after 30 days.  As it is, they wont approve any additional programs on the server (it is already in "production"), and Foundation itself specifically has the information management portions removed.

So, as i understand it, i think my only hope might be PowerShell (which is allowed, and would be close enough to "automatic" that it should work for that requirement).  Problem is, I can't really find any concrete information on if it can work, or how i would do it.  Anyone have any advice?  It literally is nothing more than removing files (not folders) older than 30 days..

Comment: Where does all these files reside, a single document library or do you have several libraries spread on several site collections?  Are you allowed to deploy Timer Jobs?

Comment: @eric It is in a single document library, in one site collection. 
I do not know of any reason why a timer job would not be allowed, assuming it does not require developed code (at this point, we are limited to what can be scripted)

Comment: It could work. You will need to put your powershell script to Windows Task Scheduler so it runs automatically.  Do you have any already written code?